# Auto span tag inside td

Tags: visualforce, html, table

I have problem with automatically added span tag in the td element.
My code in visualforce page is following:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
 <thead class="headerRow">
  <th>Comission Name</th>
  <th>Benchmark rate</th>
  <th>Fee</th>
  <th>Fee Units</th>
  <th>Payment date</th>
 </thead>
 <apex:repeat value="{!Margin}" var="m" >
  <tr>
   <td><apex:inputField value="{!m.Commission_for__c}" styleClass="form-control" html-disabled="true"/></td>
   <td>{!m.Benchmark__c}</td>
   <td><apex:inputField value="{!m.Rate__c}" styleClass="form-control"/></td>
   <td>{!m.Rate_Units__c}</td>       
   <td><apex:inputField value="{!m.Payment_Date__c}" styleClass="form-control"/></td>
  </tr>
 </apex:repeat>
</table>
```

The last td element has no span element.
but in the console log it shows:

```
<td>
 <span>
  <select id="j_id0:Form:j_id12:0:j_id18" name="j_id0:Form:j_id12:0:j_id18"> 
   <option value="">--None--</option><option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
   <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
  </select>
 </span>
</td>
```

Why the span element added automatically? and how to remove this element from td?

Answer (score 0):

Span element gets added automatically by default.

Can you use a component with `<apex:component layout="none">` and use the component in the page?

Else: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222537/avoid-salesforce-apex-components-being-wrapped-with-span-elements can help? (may not be a great option, but hey - it works!)

Typically you assume `span` and code your CSS likewise.